# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Boolean'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I got this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Boolean', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DunyaYazilim.Models.TBL_CATEGORIES'.
```

here is my view :

```
@model DunyaYazilim.Models.TBL_CATEGORIES
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditCategory";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Administrator"))
{
    <div>
        <div>Category Name</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

here is controller:

```
public ActionResult EditCategory(int CategoryID)
{
    return PartialView(entity.TBL_CATEGORIES.Select(c=>c.CategoryID==CategoryID).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

And actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("update", "EditCategory", "Administrator", new { CategoryID = categories.CategoryID }, new { @class = "openDialog", dialog_id = "EditCategory", dialog_title = "Update Category" })
```

Thanks.

Comment: check your entity.TBL_CATEGORIES.Select(c=>c.CategoryID==CategoryI) statement and makesure you are selecing several values not just one that could be bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your select statement is the cause of the problem - its returning the bool - I think you meant the c=>c.CategoryID==CategoryID to either be in a Where or in the FirstOrDefault (depending on your data source - I don't think EF 4.0 support claues in FirstOrDefault)

try

```
public ActionResult EditCategory(int CategoryID)
{
    return PartialView(entity.TBL_CATEGORIES.Where(c=>c.CategoryID==CategoryID).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

the Select is intended to Project a result, not be the where clause.

Comment: yes you right. This is the "copy-paste" disadventage :) Thanks. I could not see.

Comment: then you should click the tick box to accept this :-) (I'm trying to get to 5k points today!!)